# Make Web Part 2 display as “blank” until an item in Web Part 1 is selected ?SPD 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

I use Miscellaneous tab and de-select the “Send first row to connected Web Parts when page loads” option. but still get records when page load.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with JsLink. also ref http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80488/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-the-connected-item-of-listview not exactly your problem but might set you on the right course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build your connection as the following

**At the second list :**

- At the web part menu.
- Select Connection > `Get Filter value from` the first list.
- At connection setting > Select Provider  , Consumer Field name.

**At the first list :**

- At the web part menu.
- Select Edit Web Part.
- Below Miscellaneous > uncheck `Send first row to connected Web Parts when page loads`.

**[Output]**

At first list, no items have been selected at the first load and the second list  is blank as shown below :

[image]